# Updating parts of a .php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to update a page and proceeding the next function, similar to refreshing it?

I have a page that when **Save** button is pressed, it will submit the data into **earnings_amendment_account_add.php**, and the page will be refreshed.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve through AJAX is for the data to be submitted, and then display **Success Notification** and refresh the **dataTable** upon pressing **Save** in my modal.

Example, this part of the page `<?php include 'includes/notif-info-display.php'; ?>` will trigger this upon submitting a page.

This Screenshot only displays after I submit the form and the page was refreshed.

[image: 1]

```
 <section class="content">
    <div id = "content">
<?php include 'panels/accounting_panel.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/notif-info-display.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Now, I did some modifications to avoid refreshing the page. It will send the data to the database, but I cant' find a way for the dataTable to be refreshed, and for `<?php include 'includes/notif-info-display.php'; ?>` to be reloaded and display if it is Success or Fail, based on the triggers in my `earnings_amendment_account_add.php`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Listen to click event on the submit button
  $('#add').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // Add trigger based on button name, value
    var add = $("#add").val();

    var add_accountcode = $("#add_accountcode").val();
    var accounttitle = $("#accounttitle").val();
    var accounttype = $("#accounttype").val();
    var postedby = $("#postedby").val();
    var dateposted = $("#dateposted").val();

    $.post("earnings_amendment_account_add.php", 
    {

    // Add trigger based on button name, value
      add: add,

      add_accountcode: add_accountcode,
      accounttitle: accounttitle,
      accounttype: accounttype,
      postedby: postedby,
      dateposted: dateposted
    }).complete(function() {
        console.log("Success");
      });
  });
});
```

The trigger comes from *earnings_amendment_account_add.php* page

```
        if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET))){
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'Earnings Amendment Account Data added successfully';
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['error'] = $conn->echo .print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        }
    }   
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fill up add form first';
    }
?>
```

This is the *includes/notif-info-display.php*

```
     <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
          echo "
            <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              <h4><i class='icon fa fa-warning'></i> Error!</h4>
              ".$_SESSION['error']."
            </div>
          ";
          unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
          echo "
            <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              <h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Success!</h4>
              ".$_SESSION['success']."
            </div>
          ";
          unset($_SESSION['success']);
        }
      ?>
```

This happens after I click this the #addnew modal's submit.

```
<form autocomplete='off' class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="earnings_amendment_account_add.php">

FORMS HERE ---

    <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
                <!-- Add Button ID, Change Type to button, add name, add value -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" name="add" value="add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Everything works perfectly fine, the data is added, my only problem is that I can't seem to find a way for `<?php include 'includes/notif-info-display.php'; ?>` to be reloaded again and display the **Success Notification** upon pressing save.

This is my modal.

[image: 2]

> Is there a way for this to happen? `<?php include 'includes/notif-info-display.php'; ?>` will be reloaded and display if the Data Submitted was a success, or a failure, and at the same time, refresh the dataTable and show the latest data there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";`
after your `if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){`for the reload. 
Also set `$activateSuccess = true;` here.
Then echo your message with

`if($activateSuccess == true) {
        echo "
            <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              <h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Success!</h4></div>";
    }
    return;`

Comment: This is all inside ````notif-info-display.php````, right?

Answer (score 1):

You must handle this issue on your jquery code.In php code handling the ajax request you must send back the success data as JSON. Then in your ajax request complete section, handle this data, create a table row to add to your Datatable and pop a success notification.
Php does not update partially. this is a matter of client, php runs in server.

Comment: May I ask for some guide regarding this matter, I'm not quite sure on how to approach this.